# How do I create a view that overlaps the action bar?

Tags: android

I have created a full screen menu. When the menu is open, I would like it to occupy the whole screen, including the space occupied by the action bar. I am animating the menu in a way that would make simply hiding the action unacceptable.

My question is, is there a way that I can animate the menu over the action bar, and settle over it so that the bar is obscured by the menu?

Is it possible to attach a view to action_bar_overlay_layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a custom dialog for the fullscreen menu, and animate the dialog/its content as you need. Basically if you need the dialog to be fullscreen you can request the proper window mode like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(...);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
...
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I want a full screen overlap, I wrap the whole original layout in a relative layout, and then inflate the overlapping view which has fill_parent attributes, and add it to the outer relative layout.

If you want the original view to be dimmed, then use the alpha transparency in the background color.

But I'm not sure if this will overlap the action bar, since I don't use it for compatibility reasons.